# drag-data-get signal fired twice python gtk3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I want the source to be the destination too. I implemented the signals below but the drag-data-get signal fires twice. The second time the data variable(in on_drag_data_get) is being populated with the autoselected ListStore item.

```
class DragSource(Gtk.TreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.TreeView.__init__(self)

        model = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.set_model(model)
        self.add_item("Item 1")
        self.add_item("Item 2")
        self.add_item("Item 3")

        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Backlog", renderer, text=0)
        self.append_column(column)

        self.enable_model_drag_source(
            Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK, [], DRAG_ACTION)
        self.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], DRAG_ACTION)

        self.connect("drag-data-get", self.on_drag_data_get)
        self.connect("drag-data-received", self.on_drag_data_received)

    def on_drag_data_get(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print("fired")
        model, iter = self.get_selection().get_selected()
        text = model.get_value(iter, 0)
        data.set_text(text, -1)

    def on_drag_data_received(self, widget, drag_context, x, y, data, info, time):
        text = data.get_text()
        self.add_item(text)
        print("Received text: %s" % text)


    def add_item(self, text):
        self.get_model().append([text])
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```py
self.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], DRAG_ACTION)
```

with

```py
dnd_list = [Gtk.TargetEntry.new("text/uri-list", 0, 80)]
self.drag_dest_set_target_list(dnd_list)
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it had an explanation of the code here. Without an explanation, this answer really isn't valuable to users looking for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, signal handler will be called twice,

to fix this you have to stop event propagation by returning True from your callbacks, e.g. on_drag_data_get and on_drag_data_received

minimal show case:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def on_click(*args, **kwargs):
    print('clicked')
    return True  # to prevent event from propagation and stop event from being fired twice

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect('button-press-event', on_click)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

credit to this [comment](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136430#c1)