# Python GTK 3 button-press-event triggering twice

Tags: python, events, gtk

I create a `Gtk.Window` and connect the `"button-press-event"`. When this window is clicked, the event is triggered twice. Minimal example:

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")

from gi.repository import Gtk

w = Gtk.Window()
w.set_size_request(800, 800)
w.connect("button-press-event", lambda a, b: print(b))
w.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

This prints `b` twice. At first I thought it was somehow a press/release but, as far as I can tell, the `b` object is the same both times (it's a different instance, but with the same values). Anyone know what is going on?

I'm using python 3.8.10 and gi version 3.36.0.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65127086/16775594) is a similar question I found. I tried what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67961269/16775594) suggested (using a function, and `return True`), and it worked. Except that double-clicks fired _three_ `Gdk.EventButton`s. Unfortunately, I don't know _why_ this is happening, which could potentially be useful knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Sylvester. I guess there might be some event propagation going on that I'm unaware of, but I can't seem to find it. Really odd. As a workaround, I attached the button-press-event to a child widget, which seems to be working for now.

Comment: If you click on a window, all kinds of things happen in the background. Typically, good app development uses clicks on buttons using the 'clicked' signal.

Answer (score 0):

## Empêcher l'événement "button-press-event" d'être déclenché deux fois

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")

from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, Gdk

def on_handle_click(widget, event):
    if event.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS :
        print(f'event.type            : {event.type}')
        print(f"Click with the button : {event.button}")
        return True
        # True : pour empêcher l'événement de se propager et empêcher l'événement d'être déclenché deux fois


w = Gtk.Window()
w.set_size_request(100, 100)
w.connect("button-press-event", on_handle_click)
w.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```